# можно ли вызвать setOnLoadCompleteListener несколько раз

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть у меня 3 фрагмента, и в каждом фрагменте есть разные звуки которые появляются при нажатии на кнопки, и я вызываю `setOnLoadCompleteListener` в каждый фрагмент, но в двух фрагментом звук пристанет появляться.

я не могу понять почему.

```
  mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            loaded = true;

        }
    });
```

и когда я проверяю на `true`, возвращает `false` и кнопка не работает.
хотя если я уберу проверку , тогда кнопка работает и звук появиться.

```
 if (loaded) {
   Sound.playSound(mBisonSound);
   Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), R.string.Bison, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   Snackbar.make(view, R.string.Bison, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Comment: У вас sound pool один на три фрагмента? Или а каждом свой?

Comment: у меня есть статический класс ٍsoundPager и оттуда я вызываю SoundPool, получаеться один на три фрагмента.

Comment: Проблема в том, что Вы перезаписываете onLoadComplete три раза, в каждом из которых меняете loaded текущего класса. Другими словами, Вам необходимо перенести переменную loaded в ваш класс sound Pager и менять его там

Comment: спасибо большое, получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

из комментариев

Проблема в том, что Вы перезаписываете `onLoadComplete` три раза, в каждом из которых меняете `loaded` текущего класса. Другими словами, Вам необходимо перенести переменную `loaded` в ваш класс `sound Pager` и менять его там – [Daniel Shatz](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/192419/daniel-shatz) 25 дек '15 в 17:25